# Импорт csv файла в sqlite с помощью sqlite3.exe (андроид)

Tags: android, sqlite3

Задача максимально быстро импортировать csv файлы в sqlite.

Сделал через цикл очень долго получается.
По шарил по инету и нашел, что можно с помощью sqlite3 сделать импорт я так понимаю он должен быть самым быстрым.

Вот как я делаю.

```
@Override
public void onSuccess(int statusCode, Header[] headers, File file) {

   db.execSQL(".mode csv");
   db.execSQL(".import "+file.getPath() + " " + TablePrices.TABLE_NAME);
}
```

Но не получается загрузить выдает ошибку ...http://clip2net.com/s/3mxTYdE
Что я не так делаю не понимаю.

```
08-24 13:05:17.092    3970-3970/ua.com.it_st.ordersmanagers V/AsyncHttpRH﹕ Progress 14 from 14 (100%)
08-24 13:05:17.092    3970-3970/ua.com.it_st.ordersmanagers E/SQLiteLog﹕ (1) near ".": syntax error
08-24 13:05:17.092    3970-3970/ua.com.it_st.ordersmanagers E/AsyncHttpRH﹕ User-space exception detected!
    android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near ".": syntax error (code 1): , while compiling: .mode csv
            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativePrepareStatement(Native Method)
            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.acquirePreparedStatement(SQLiteConnection.java:882)
            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.prepare(SQLiteConnection.java:493)
            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.prepare(SQLiteSession.java:588)
            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.<init>(SQLiteProgram.java:58)
            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement.<init>(SQLiteStatement.java:31)
            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.executeSql(SQLiteDatabase.java:1663)
            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.execSQL(SQLiteDatabase.java:1594)
            at ua.com.it_st.ordersmanagers.utils.AsyncHttpClientUtil$1.onSuccess(AsyncHttpClientUtil.java:55)
```

Comment: В android не используются .exe файлы. Вы выполняете этот кода на android устройстве или на локальной машине?

Comment: я выполняю код на эмуляторе в андроиде.

Comment: Я пробовал использовать инструкцию как здесь http://www.sqlite.org/cli.html написано, но применить к андроиду результат то же.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> #### Special commands to `sqlite3`
>
> Most of the time, `sqlite3` just reads lines of input and passes them on to the SQLite library for execution. But if an input line begins with a dot ("."), then that line is intercepted and interpreted by the `sqlite3` program itself.

[Читайте внимательнее](http://www.sqlite.org/cli.html).

Перевод:

> #### Особые команды для `sqlite3`
>
> Обычно `sqlite3` просто считывает введённые строки и передаёт на выполнение библиотеке SQLite. Но если ввод начинается с точки ("."), то строчки перехватываются и интерпретируются самой утилитой `sqlite3`.

Важно в этом то, что `.команд` в **библиотеке** SQLite (которой вы и пользуетесь) нет. *Только в утилите для командной строки `sqlite3`.* Которой посвящена вся указанная страница.

Раз библиотека SQLite не содержит этой команды, разбирать CSV вам придётся средствами Java. Лучше найти библиотеку, которая этим занимается, и импортировать CSV пачками по 100-1000 строк на запрос (лучше экспериментально выяснить максимум).

Comment: Я не совсем понимаю до конца в андроиде есть sqlite3 или нет, могу я внутри оболочки андроида воспользоваться утилитой sqlite3?

Comment: @GensJava там нет утилиты `sqlite3`, а библиотека SQLite есть.

Comment: Я хотел бы поставить точку в этом вопросе т.е я не могу сделать импорт csv файла  через какую-то команду SQLite, загружать можно только к примеру только читая файл через  цикл?

Comment: @GensJava ну, я бы вооружился библиотечкой-парсером CSV и загружал файл в базу построчно.

Comment: Я так и делаю тока без библиотек, больше всего времени уходит не на чтение файла, а на запись во время команды insert.

Comment: @GensJava окей, про "построчно" может быть вредным советом -- нарежьте на крупные пачки (записей по 100-1000?) и вставляйте одним здоровым запросом каждую пачку. Боюсь, больше помочь ничем не смогу -- мой опыт импорта CSV ограничивается импортом в PostgreSQL с помощью Ruby, там некоторый прирост в скорости дала транзакция. Поскольку SQLite для одного пользователя, тут это вряд ли что-то даст.

Comment: А еще вариант я тут попробовал через консоль сделать импорт на компе http://clip2net.com/s/3mCisfZ загрузилась таблица 23 000 строк 1 сек наверно может меньше.
Если я создам на компе базу и скопирую ее на андроид работать будет, практика есть такая?

Comment: @GensJava попробовать стоит. Не вижу причин, по которым это не должно сработать.

Comment: @GensJava Да, готовую базу можно поместить в приложение и такая практика есть и довольно распространена. БД помещается в папку /assets, а при первом запуске приложения она копируется на устройство. В инете достаточно примеров готовой реализации.

Comment: Спасибо, всем за ответы - советы! Задачу решил с помощью нарезки строк на 100-1000 как  посоветовал  D-side, 30 000 строк загружается 5-10 сек мне подходит, подскажите еще как тут плюс поставить человеку (D-side) за помощь?

Comment: @GensJava я не думал, что вы воспользуетесь этим советом. Добавил его в ответ, раз такое дело. Если считаете, что он привёл вас к решению, отметьте его галочкой.

Comment: Отметил. Тут http://clip2net.com/s/3mDyXbt ?

Comment: @GensJava да. Но рекомендую пройти [тур](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/tour) и узнать всё из первых рук.